# Google Apps Script: Export Dashboard to CSV

Tags: charts, google-apps-script, google-sheets, export-to-csv, dashboard

I've created a Dashboard similar to the example provided on the Google Apps Script [Help Center](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/charts_dashboard). It contains controls which filters the spreadsheet that contains the data. I would like to add an option on the dashboard that would allow the users to export the filtered view to a new CSV file or Google Sheets file that would be saved in their Drive however I've no idea how to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snippet from Google tutorial:

```
function saveAsCSV() {
  // Prompts the user for the file name
  var fileName = Browser.inputBox("Save CSV file as (e.g. myCSVFile):");

  // Check that the file name entered wasn't empty
  if (fileName.length !== 0) {
    // Add the ".csv" extension to the file name
    fileName = fileName + ".csv";
    // Convert the range data to CSV format
    var csvFile = convertRangeToCsvFile_(fileName);
    // Create a file in the Docs List with the given name and the CSV data
    DocsList.createFile(fileName, csvFile);
  }
  else {
    Browser.msgBox("Error: Please enter a CSV file name.");
  }
}*
```

View the [full tutorial and code here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial#section-3-saving-a-selected-range-to-a-csv-file).